# Difficult general integral definite 0 to 1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1} \log^2(x)\cdot x^{k+1} dx$$

I tried integration by parts but it leads to an extremely complicated computation, which didnt lead me anywhere.

Then

I tried differentiating the beta function. That was partly successful. But the problem was when I substituted $k+2$ in and then the digammas and trigamma acted out.

Any help?

Thanks!

Series, and ANY type EXCEPT COMPLEX ANALYSIS is welcome.

Comment: What about substitution: $u=\log(x)$?

Comment: @Karl: That gives $\int_{-\infty}^0 u^2 e^{ku}\,du$ if I'm not mistaken.  I don't know if that's easier but maybe it makes it more obvious that one should proceed by integration by parts (which could also be done without the substitution as in Martin's answer).

Comment: But here you have now the Gamma function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, consider this integral:
$$I(k)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+1} dx=\frac{1}{k+2}$$

The desired integral is:
$$I''(k)=\int_0^1\log^2(x)\cdot x^{k+1}dx=\frac{2}{(k+2)^3}$$

Comment: can you please show more steps? I don't get the approach. Thanks.

Comment: This is an example of differentiating to a paramater, or differentiating under the integral, also called Feynman integration. The summary is that $I(k)$ defines a function of $k$, differentiable in this example. Under certain conditions, when differentiating with respect to $k$, it is allowed to calculate this by differentiating the function inside the integral.

Comment: +1. Fine.$\mbox{}$

Answer (score 7):

Thijs solution is very elegant. But the computation can be done without appealing to any theorems (you need one if you want to justify differentiation under the integral sign).

We have, integrating by parts twice,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \log^2(x)\cdot x^{k+1} dx&=\left.\phantom{\int\!\!\!\!}\frac{x^{k+2}}{k+2}\,\log^2x\right|_0^1-\frac2{k+2}\left.\phantom{\int\!\!\!\!}\frac{x^{k+2}}{k+2}\log x\right|_0^1+\frac2{(k+2)^2}\int_0^1x^{k+1}dx\\
&=\frac2{(k+2)^2}\int_0^1x^{k+1}dx\\
&=\frac2{(k+2)^3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The two answers are excellent, but there is a third giving something interesting, i.e. a relation to the Gamma function:
$$\int_0^1 \log(x)^2 x^{k+1}\ dx=$$
Substituting $u=-\log(x)$:
$$\int_0^{\infty} u^2 \exp(-(k+1)u)\exp(-u)\ du=$$
Substituting $v=(k+2)u$:
$$(k+2)^{-3}\int_0^{\infty} v^2 \exp(-v)\ dv= (k+2)^{-3} \Gamma(3)=2(k+2)^{-3} $$